# Javascript mssql update string escape

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I'm trying to update some columns in my mssql so I build queries like this `Update Test set Notes = 'Hello',total = 20` and It works nice, the problem comes when I try to insert something like that `Update Test set Notes = 'it's my first note',total = 20` the problem is that because of the second `'` I can't insert it. I tried to replace it to espace to set it `\'` through regex `value.replace(/[(')]/gm,replacer)` it did what is should but when I executed the query `pool.request().query(query)` it didn't work.

package

```js
"mssql": "^6.2.1"
```

Just to understand how I'm doing that

```js
const myString = {
  first: async () => {
    const doc = {
      notes: "it's my first note",
      total: 20
    }
    const str = [];
    for await (const [key, value] of Object.entries(doc)) {
      
        str.push(
          `${key} = '${typeof value == "string" ? value.replace(/[('`)]/gm,replacer) : value}'`
        );
    }
    return `Update test set ${str} where id = 10`
  }
}
const query = await myString[first]();
//the query will be something like Update test set Notes = 'it\'s my first note',total = 20 where id = 10
await pool.request().query(query).catch(console.error);
```

Error:

> message: "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' where id = 10'.",

Answer (score 0):

You should replace it by '' (double single quotes, not double quoutes), instead of `\'`
So your replacer should be this:

```
replacer = '\'\''
```

Comment: So if i have a single `'` I need to add a second one? so this `'it\'s my first note'` should look like this `'it\'\'s my first note'`?

Comment: Yes in mssql you need to use two single quotes to enclose them

Comment: Oh sorry missed a bit, your actually query will look like “it’’s...”

Comment: `"Incorrect syntax near '\\'."`, error I get after implementig that